# Faking Input Like GlovePIE

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, kinect

I have been programming against Kinect, and I now want to have games react to what I am doing on the Kinect. It is real easy to send data to notepad for key presses, but much harder to send it to games.

First off, I have been using the WPF Skeleton example from Kinect and building off that for now. I could use the C++ version but my C++ is very rusty, and I would prefer not to.

So here is what I have done so far, I have tried `SendKeys`, `SendInput`, `keybd_event`, `Post_Message`. None of those make it to games like Burnout Paradise.

I do know GlovePIE input gets to games, but how?  Currently my work around/hack, is to use PPJoy, which has sample code in C++ to emulate button presses.  I call this via  [DllImport] from my WPF app.  I then pickup the joystick button presses in GlovePIE and have it convert those to Keyboard Keys.  So I go around in a circle, which works but PPJoys driver is not signed, so I can't really share this code as people would have to allow test-signed drivers.

Does anyone know how GlovePIE makes their Keypresses happen?  I have posted on the GlovePIE Forums, but no responses. GlovePIE has a little bit of a hack to work with the old openNI kinect drivers, but I am using the standard microsoft version recently released a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not sure what the scoop is on answering your own question, but I figured out the whole proper solution and wanted to share as the Checked off Answer.

First Include this using statement

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Then Put this in your class this in your class

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void Keybd_event(byte vk, byte scan, int flags, int extrainfo);
```

This will import the C method for use in C#.
Now some games / application use Virtual Keys VKey and some (Direct X aka DIKey) use Scancodes.  My problem was I used the scan codes improperly so it did not work for some games.  I suggest if you do not know what application wants to consume these, you call it twice one with Virtual Key and one for Direct Input Key

Here is an example of two calls for the letter 'A' using Virtual Keys then using Direct Input Keys.

```
KEYDOWN = 0
KEYUP = 2
//Virtual Key
Keybd_event(65, 0, KEYDOWN, 0);

//Direct Input Key
Keybd_event(0, 30, KEYDOWN, 0);
```

As you can tell the values for A are different from VK to DIK
Both of the links relate to the HEX values, while my samples above show Base 10 (Integers)

VKeys link  http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm

DIKeys link http://community.bistudio.com/wiki/DIK_KeyCodes

This should also work for SendInput also, but I have not fully verified that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know GlovePIE, sorry, but perhaps these might help.

PostMessage and SendMessage get different behaviour when dealing with emulating keystrokes.
Would also help to know what message your actually sending, keydown/up, keypress etc.

You may need to do something about changing the focus - maybe the wrong element is selected, or your sending to the wrong (sub)window.

Similarly if you where emulating mouse clicks there can also be checks for where the mouse is to ensure it is still on the clickable area.

Consider also holding a key down triggers a repeat mechanism sending multiple key messages, commonly in games your holding the key down to turn not just tapping it once.

Comment: I have "held" down the keys by using a sleep then sending the keyup command.  Everything works great in notepad, I also don't want to have to specify the window/subwindow I am sending the keystrokes too.  So I can't keep it game/application agnostic.  Thanks for some ideas though.

Comment: depending on some variety of things, an app may be expecting more than keyup taking some time - or ignoring that and using something else, such as seeing multiple 'wm_char' messages.  ` ::SendMessage(hWND, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
::SendMessage(hWND, WM_CHAR,VK_RETURN,0);
::SendMessage(hWND, WM_CHAR,VK_RETURN,0);
::SendMessage(hWND, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, 0);
`

Answer (score 0):

While I will not say this is the best answer, I wanted to round back with the solution I am using.  I have found that I can use vJoy http://headsoft.com.au/index.php?category=vjoy which is signed, so it can be used in Windows 7 64 bit.  I can the call this extern keybd_event

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "keybd_event", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern void Keybd_event(byte vk, byte scan, int flags, int extrainfo);
```

From there I can `Keybd_event(CKEY, SCANCODE, KEYDOWN, 0);` then X frame later call `Keybd_event(CKEY, SCANCODE, KEYUP, 0);`

I set vJoy to read in "c" or other keys I send via keybd_event.  vJoy reads this properly and then "presses" the associated button which GlovePIE picks up.  So in GlovePIE my script look like

```
A = joystick1.Button1
Z = joystick1.Button2
```

Which works in the games I have tried.
It is definitely not idea, but it works and allows end user to customize the input via vJoy and GlovePIE.